# Python Logging: Evaluate Time before adding a new entry

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, logging, timestamp

I am editing a python-script to control home appliances (sonos, hue etc.) with the log of a plex mediaserver.

So far things went well, now i am struggeling with a question i could not find an answer to. These are my first steps, please bear with me.

I have a log file, which collects session information in this format:

> ...
>
> 2014-09-13 14:40:02 johnedoe is watching 30c3 Keynote
>
> 2014-09-13 14:48:06 thomas is watching Band of Brothers
>
> 2014-09-13 15:28:03 johnedoe is watching The Zero Theorem
>
> ...

if a new session is detected, the script evaluates if the part "johnedoe is watching 30c3 Keynote" is already present. i would like to include a timestamp-check, which would not only examine if the session is present, but also if a already logged session is older than two hours.

> In pseudocode:  if (alert not in log) or (if alert in log and older than two hours):

Can i access the corresponding timestamp directly, or to i have to regex the line? Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

This is the tail of code:

```
logLocation = '/storage/downloads/plexMon.log'  
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', filename=logLocation, level=logging.INFO)
log = open(logLocation).read()
server = urllib2.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:32400/status/sessions') 
data = server.read()
server.close()
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
for video in tree.iter('Video'):
  show = video.get('grandparentTitle')
  episode = video.get('title')
  if show == "None":
    title = episode
  else:
    title = '%s - %s' % (show, episode)
    user = video.find('User').get('title').split('@')[0]
  alert = '%s is watching %s' % (user, title)
  if alert not in log:
    logging.info(alert)
    if all(i not in alert for i in ignoreAlertList):
      sendAlert(alert)
      if user == "johnedoe":
          b = Bridge('192.168.1.109') 
          b.set_light(1, 'bri', 50)
          my_zone = SoCo('192.168.1.105')
          my_zone.unjoin()
          my_zone.pause()
```

Comment: If the timestamp is of fixed length and you get line by line log updates, you shouldn't need a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without regexes, this may be easier to achieve, if you use:

```
log_lines = open(logLocation).readlines() # read log files as a list[] of lines
```

instead of:

```
log = open(logLocation).read()
```

and then use something like:

```
for line in log_lines:
    if(line.__contains__(alert)):
        partsOfLine = str(line).split()
        dateParts = str(partsOfLine[0]).split("-")
        timeParts = str(partsOfLine[1]).split(":")
        alerttime = datetime.datetime(int(dateParts[0]),int(dateParts[1]),int(dateParts[2]),int(timeParts[0]),int(timeParts[1]),int(timeParts[2]))
        timediff_in_min = (alerttime - datetime.now()).total_seconds()/60
        if(timediff_in_min >= 120):
            print "ignoring older than 2 hours"
        else:
            print "new alert in the last 2 hours"
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a bunch for this suggestion. Exactly what i was looking for. I integrated the Code, with some modifications and fixes, in the final script and it works great. Thanks! 
This is the [Gist-Link](https://gist.github.com/noestreich/f434632b00bbdec3d76a) if anybody is interested.